# Vuetify data table slot group.summary

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am working with a vuetify data table, I am using the groub-by slot to group my items either by category or location that is working fine. What I am trying to do now is add a summary row for each group.

this is my current code for the grouping and attempt at summary row

```
 <v-data-table
          v-if="reportType === 'Category' || reportType === 'Location'"
          :headers="headers"
          :items="assets"
          disable-pagination
          disable-filtering
          hide-default-footer
          disable-sort
          :group-by="`${reportType.toLowerCase()}Name`"
          class="elevation-1">
        <template v-slot:group="{ items }">
          <tr>
            <td class="text-xs-right" :colspan="fixGroupByHeaders()"><strong>{{ getGroupByName(items[0]) }}</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr v-for="(item) in items" :key="item.id">
            <td v-for="(header, index) in headers" :key="index">
              {{ (getTotalCost(item, header.value) || item[header.value]) }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:group.summary="{ items }">
          <tr>
            <th class="title">Totals</th>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
```

the groupby is working but th e summary is not .. I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it to where I get the summary row using the grouby.summary slot found on the vuetify data table api.

EDIT:
I understand about the group.summary slot and I can easily make it if the report headers were static, in this case they are not.

So, I created a CodeSandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-babycat-xd5vb?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) that I hope will show you what I am trying to achieve and as I said the headers array is dynamic.

Another thing is I added an array called columnsToTotal to show what columns need a total added if they are present in the headers array.

Comment: You are missing equal sign, is it a typo? v-slot:group.summary". Plus why you "use" the items when you don't use the items farther?

Comment: It was a typo, i edited the question to better reflect my code, Items was a test to see if it would work. but it did not .. again not sure what I am doing wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use both *group* and *group.summary* slots simultaneously.

*group.header* and *group.summary* slots is just a "sub-slots" of *group* slot. When you are overriding *group* slot, the "sub-slots" simply does not exist.

I'm not clearly understand what are you trying to achieve, but perhaps this tip will be useful to you.

If you want to customize...

1. ...your group header, use **group.header** slot
2. ...your group rows, use **item** slot
3. ...your group footer, use **group.summary** slot
4. ...the whole group, use **group** slot

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown. What I am trying to achieve is to get the subtotal of my total current value and total purchase price columns of my data I want to show them in the group summary. I just needed to know how the group summary slot worked in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get my summary row. itemTotal is a method.

```
<template v-slot:group.summary="{ items }">
    <th colspan="7"></th>
    <th>
       <span class="ml-10">
          Charge Total: {{ itemTotal(items) }}
       </span>
    </th>
</template>
```